# Why is ubuntu 20.04 slow in a dual boot system with Windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, xubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 (dual boot). I did it by installing Ubuntu on a USB and then I installed Ubuntu from the USB. I have already done it for my old pc and, in that case, both the Operating Systems worked perfectly (was it just the begginner's luck?) ! In this latest case (my new pc), instead, Ubuntu is really slow and I do not understand why !

**When I say that Ubuntu is slow**, I mean that everything is slow: if I open the broswer web, if I open applications like RStudio, Spyder etc... If I do all these things too fast together, it crashes !

Is it maybe due to the characteristics of the pc ? What can I do to fix this issue ? I have also to say that I have installed also xubuntu (for a mistake... I did not remember how it happened). Also this fact could be a source of slowness ?

Below are the infromation about my pc:

1. **RAM**: 4,00 GB (3,83 usable)
2. **CPU**: Intel(R) Celeron(R) N4000 CPU @ 1.10GHz   1.10 GHz
3. **System type**: 64-bit operating system x64-based processor
4. **Card name**: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 600

Sorry if I am not very precise in the description but I do these things without a deep consciousness and knowledge.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I think I have written everything you asked. To be honest, indeed, I do not know if I am using any proprietary graphics drivers but now I try to find also this information. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm, there is no NVidia card? Usually Intel cards are very well supported in Ubuntu, and such issues does not usually occur in Ubuntu.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi no I am pretty sure .

Comment: Thank you very much @StephenMichaelKellat !

Answer (score 0):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: For the older computer, I had the same RAM and it worked perfectly with the same amount of programs... But I will try as you suggest .